# Matching a pattern using web scraping

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I want to get all the problems solved by a user on a website by using regular expression to get only the problem code through it. For example if `<a href="/status/PROBLEM,user/">PROBLEM</a>` is the HTML code I want to get only the PROBLEM from it. This is the php function which I wrote to accomplish this.

```
public function filter($s, $u) {
        //$u -> username
        //$s -> string containing html code
        $reg= "/[^<a href=\"\/status\/(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]|\_|[a-z]|\.)*\"$u]/";
        $solved = preg_split($reg, $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
        return $solved[0];
}
```

The regular expression doesn't seem to be correct and I am only getting `/[^` when I print `$reg`. Also, I am not sure if `preg_split()` is the right function to return to do this. Please help.

Comment: My first question to you is: Do you really need to scrape the HTML? I'm not gonna tell you not to, just making sure this is actually want you want and that you wouldn't be better off with something else.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra I couldn't find any other way to do what I want to.

Comment: Even when I escape < I am getting /[^\ when I print `$reg`. And yes I want to include a , in between PROBLEM and USER.

Comment: I don't know why but even when I do that I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: `<` is not a "meta character" and don't need to be escaped.

Comment: The shown code has a `syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN` - post the code you actually used.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.  Note that instead of searching for the `PROBLEM` text in the link as you were attempting, I search for the `PROBLEM` text that is being highlighted.  The `$u` parameter no longer seems necessary.

```
public function filter($s) {
    // $s set to '<a href="/status/PROBLEM,user/">PROBLEM</a>';
    $reg = '#<a href="[^"]+">(?P<problem>.+)</a>#i';
    preg_match($reg, $s, $matches);
    return $matches['problem']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer brackets in your regular expression are out of place.